# Crop a rectangle from an image given the exact coordinates using C++

Tags: c++, image

Is there a way to do this using fread/fwrite? I have the exact coordinates of the rectangle from the image I want to crop.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but it will almost certainly require some processing.  What is the image format?

Comment: What kind of image (i.e. which container/codec)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most image files are more complex than just an array of pixels. They often contain headers with metadata and compress the image data in some way.

Editing them is often done with some sort of library, such as [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php). These libraries contain classes and functions for

- opening image files and reading in the image data
- Modifying the image data with built-in functions, such as cropping, scaling, etc.
- Getting access to the raw image data (often exposed as an array of pixels) so the programmer can modify it in ways not provided by the library.
- saving image files

Answer (score 3):

I personally recommend you CImg, an "small, open source, C++ toolkit for image processing". All you have to do is to include a header file, download it from http://cimg.sourceforge.net/, load the image from the file using the CImg library and then use the `crop` function.